# Admob showing ads in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, admob

This is the code that I am currently using to show some ads on my device. But it doesn't seem to work as of now. Need some guidance on what could be going wrong here.

```
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,468,320,50)];
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a153b29f919d822";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
//self.adBanner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
[self.adBanner loadRequest:r];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have recently setup up your account in Google AdMob, it is going to take sometime for the ads to start appearing on the device.

But you can try setting testDevices in your `GADRequest`. The device Id will be being printed out in your console by the AdMob SDK.

Then add the below code.

`r.testDevices = @["test_device_id"];`

Comment: i exactly did as you told but still no luck.It goes to this - (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error method and logs No ad to show...

Comment: Ok. Hope u added the right device Id that's provided in the console? If you have, then I think you can give it sometime.